# Why isn't Oracle converting characters to numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle throws `ORA-01722: invalid number` in my SQL query and it is unclear why.

I have a table called "LIGHTS" and I want to get the lights with a WATTAGE <= 3. WATTAGE is stored as a VARCHAR2(40) for some reason, but each character does seem to be an integer or float. When I convert WATTAGE to a number using the query:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(WATTAGE) FROM LIGHTS
```

There's no problem. I get a result like this:

```
TO_NUMBER(WATTAGE) 
1
7
-1
0
15
17.5
```

However, when I add a WHERE condition to filter the numbers for those less than 3, I get the `ORA-01722: invalid number` error:

```
SELECT WATTAGE FROM LIGHTS
WHERE TO_NUMBER(WATTAGE) <= 3
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: BTW: it is not a good db design if you store numbers in a char column

Comment: It is quite likely that you are using a tool that initially retrieves only the first n rows. So your first query has not yet hit the faulty row. Scroll down to the last row in the query result and you'll probably get the same error.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner - this mystery is probably an artefact of an incomplete fetch. Try `select max(to_number(wattage)) from lights` and see whether that hits a broken bulb.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in `varchar` columns to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`ORA-01722: invalid number` comes from the `TO_NUMBER()`, not from the conditional. I.e., try this and you'll get the same error:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('test') FROM dual;
```

This would indicate that at least one of your values is not numeric.

Comment: But then why does ```SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(WATTAGE) FROM LIGHTS``` work?

Comment: Are you selecting every row?

Comment: What does this give you: `SELECT WATTAGE FROM LIGHTS WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(WATTAGE, '[^0-9]');`

Comment: Yeah, when I select for every row (i.e. no where condition), it works, but when I filter wattage in the where condition, it fails.

Comment: The query you suggested seems to only return the decimal numbers...doesn't return any of the integers, except for -1

Comment: Right, it should show all the rows where the field does not contain a positive integer. (I.e., the rows likely to cause an issue when passed to `TO_NUMBER()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Alas Oracle doesn't have a simple way to check whether a string is in fact representing a number. (One of the many reasons to use the correct data type in the first place!)

However, you can write your own. Here is just a brief demo of this concept. I create a table with a column of VARCHAR2 data type, and populate it with a few strings, one of which is not a number.

```
create table tbl (nbr varchar2(100));
insert into tbl
  select '103'  from dual union all
  select '-1.3' from dual union all
  select 'abc'  from dual
;
```

Then I create a small function with a nested block that should error out if `TO_NUMBER` fails. The error handler will "do something" specific to errors and then return control to the main function. Then I can use this in a WHERE clause. Here are the function and then how it can be used to find the offending values:

```
create or replace function not_a_number(str varchar2)
return varchar2
as
  x number;
  r varchar2(100);
begin
  begin
    x := to_number(str);
  exception
    when others then
    r := str;
  end;
  return r;
end;
/

select nbr
from   tbl
where  not_a_number(nbr) is not null;

NBR 
-------
abc
```